# How to convert a string to byte array?

Tags: c++, vcl

I have the following char*:

```
char*Problem = "\x8B\x15\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8B\x7C\x24\x14\x85\xC9\x74\x16\x8B\x03\x89\x01\x8B\x2D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8B\x15\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8B\x0D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x83\xC1\x04"
```

I am trying to get this:

```
unsigned char buf[] = {0x8B, 0x15, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x8B, 0x7C, 0x24, 0x14, 0x85, 0xC9, 0x74, 0x16, 0x8B, 0x03, 0x89, 0x01, 0x8B, 0x2D, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x8B, 0x15, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x8B, 0x0D, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x83, 0xC1, 0x04};
```

But by runtime.
I am reading the char* from a textbox.

I tried the following:

```
UnicodeString Maskstr = Edit2->Text; //My char*Problem above
const char *chr = AnsiString(Maskstr).c_str();
char* MaskConverted = const_cast<char*>( chr );
unsigned char NewArray[40];
strcpy( (char*) NewArray, MaskConverted  );
```

I thought, my unsigned char would be NewArray now, but it´s not. So how to get the correct result?..

I am a bit stuck right now.
Any ideas?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: stop doing C i C++ https://youtu.be/YnWhqhNdYyk

Comment: Int len = strlen(Problem) + 1; unsigned char buf[len]; strcpy(Problem,buf); but[Len -1] = 0;

Comment: @BaileyKocin `unsigned char buf[len];` is not legal in C++;

Comment: It is with c99 on a gnu compiler. VLAs

Comment: `char*Problem = "\x8B\x15\x00;` used as a C-string contains only 2-characters (and the *nul-terminating* character). The initializer is valid for all bytes, but you cannot thereafter determine the number of bytes using string functions. Better `const char Problem[] = "\x8B\x15\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8B\x7C\x24\x14..."` which then allows a determination of the number of bytes with `size_t n = sizeof Problem/sizeof *Problem;` (only within the scope where `Problem` was defined) Which is why you are better off using a container.

Comment: @MarekR that's somewhat a slippery slope. Taught literally in that manner ignores 30 years of existing code base those new C++ students will hopefully be competent to handle. Far better to learn and understand both fundamental types as well as the containers library and the benefits it offers.

Answer (score 1):

Your example improperly initializes the `Problem` variable (it is truncating data) after the 2nd byte.

But let's just assume for the sake of argument that your `TEdit` actually contains the complete text you are interested in.  Does the `TEdit` contain actual *raw bytes* that have been extended as-is to 16-bit Unicode chars, or does it contain a *hex-encoded representation* of the raw bytes?  This makes a BIG difference in how you process the text.

If the text contains *raw bytes*, then your processing code is incorrectly storing a `char*` pointer to data that belongs to a temporary `AnsiString` that gets destroyed before you use the pointer, thus exhibiting **undefined behavior**.  Don't destroy the `AnsiString` until after you have copied from it:

```cpp
AnsiString Maskstr = Edit2->Text;
unsigned char NewArray[40];
strncpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(NewArray), const_cast<char*>(s.c_str()), 40);
```

Alternatively, simply don't convert to `AnsiString` at all, you can just truncate the Unicode characters instead:

```cpp
UnicodeString Maskstr = Edit2->Text;
unsigned char NewArray[40] = {};
int maxlen = Maskstr.Length();
if (maxlen > 40) maxlen = 40;
for(int i = 0; i < maxlen; ++i) {
    NewArray = static_cast<unsigned char>(Maskstr[i+1]);
}
```

However, if the text actually contains a *hex-encoded representation* of raw bytes, then you need to *parse* the text to *decode* the hex sequences into actual bytes, eg:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

UnicodeString Maskstr = Edit2->Text;
const WideChar *ptr = Maskstr.c_str();
unsigned char NewArray[40] = {};
int maxlen = Maskstr.Length();
if (maxlen > 40) maxlen = 40;
for(int i = 0; i < maxlen; ++i)
{
    unsigned int b, numChars;
    if (swscanf(ptr, L"\\x%2x%n", &b, &numChars) != 1) break;
    NewArray[i] = static_cast<unsigned char>(b);
    ptr += numChars;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will compile tabbed hex values but I couldn't find a function to translate it - although Remy is using a scanf. I changed the tab to 0x format and used strtol.

```
// convert hex string to char/byte values
size_t TForm1::TranslateTabbedHex(const AnsiString str, std::vector<unsigned char> & result)
{
  AnsiString char_str(str);
  char * pEnd;

  size_t pos = char_str.AnsiPos("\\");
  for( ; pos; pos = char_str.AnsiPos("\\") )
  {
    if( pos != 1)
      char_str.Delete(1, pos-1);

    char_str[1] = '0';
    result.push_back( strtol(char_str.c_str(), &pEnd, 0) );
    char_str.Delete(1,1);
  }

  return result.size();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void TForm1::TestTranslateTabbedHex(std::vector<unsigned char> & result)
{
  unsigned char test_value[] = "\x8B\x15\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8B\x7C\x24\x14"
                               "\x85\xC9\x74\x16\x8B\x03\x89\x01\x8B\x2D"
                               "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8B\x15\x00\x00\x00\x00"
                               "\x8B\x0D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x83\xC1\x04";

  //"\x8B\x15\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8B\x7C\x24\x14\x85\xC9\x74\x16\x8B\x03\x89\x01\x8B\x2D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8B\x15\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8B\x0D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x83\xC1\x04"

  Memo1->Clear();

  size_t test_size =  sizeof test_value - 1;
  AnsiString length( test_size );
  Memo1->Lines->Add( AnsiString("size test_value=") + length );
  Memo1->Lines->Add( AnsiString("size result=") + result.size() );

  AnsiString text(Edit1->Text);
  if(Edit1->Text.Length() > 0)
    Memo1->Lines->Add( AnsiString("first char value in EditBox = ") + text[1]);
  else
    Memo1->Lines->Add("No text in EditBox");

  Memo1->Lines->Add(" ");

  if(result.size() == 0)
  { Memo1->Lines->Add("result = 0 length");
  }
  else
  { size_t test_size = std::min( result.size(), test_size );  // #include <algorithm>
    Memo1->Lines->Add("test  - result - same");
    for(size_t i=0; i<test_size; i++)
    { AnsiString line(test_value[i]);
      line += AnsiString("  -  ") + result[i];
      line += AnsiString("  -  ") + AnsiString((result[i] == test_value[i]) ? "Yes" : "No");
      Memo1->Lines->Add( line );
    }
  }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  std::vector<unsigned char> result;
  TranslateTabbedHex(Edit1->Text, result);
  TestTranslateTabbedHex( result );
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```